# Need help for exact match using Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

i want to match exact string

example to match "test" in below

"test"  - ismatch true

"test new" -true

"new test"- true

"testtt"- false

this is the expression

`Regex.IsMatch("input", @"/\b(test)\b/")`

it always gives false any idea ??

Comment: Because 'input' doesn't contain the word 'test' to begin with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Regex.IsMatch("input", @"/\b(test)\b/")
```

Is that JavaScript, or what is that?

Because in C#, you're trying to match literally `/test/` with that regex, not `test`. If you remove the `/` characters surrounding the actual regular expression, it'll work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you do the following:

```
Regex.IsMatch("input", @"/\b(test)\b/")
```

You're trying to match the literal string "input" against your regular expression. Assuming `input` is the variable that stores the value you're trying to match, you should specify the variable as the parameter:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"/\b(test)\b/")
```

Next, even if you do that you still won't get the expected result because your `Regex` is incorrect. The two forward slashes at the beginning and the end will prevent from any word being a correct match unless they have forward slashes in them. What you need is the following:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b(test)\b");
var input1 = "test";
var input2 = "testt";
var match1 = regex.IsMatch(input1);
var match2 = regex.IsMatch(input2);
```